# Django Error: Ensure this value has at most 5 characters (it has 6)

Tags: amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, TimeStampedModel):
    objects = UserManager()

    GENDER_MALE = "male"
    GENDER_FEMALE = "female"
    GENDER_OTHER = "other"

    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        (GENDER_MALE, "Male"),
        (GENDER_FEMALE, "Female"),
        (GENDER_OTHER, "Other"),
    )

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
```

It has the same code as above.

The service is being distributed using EB of AWS and an error "Ensure this value has at most 5 characters (it has 6)." occurred when the user set the gender to female.

The original code confirmed that the error occurred because the maximum_length of the gender was set to 5, and the code corrected to 6 is the code shown above.

However, the same error occurs in the service even after the makemigrations - migrate - eb deploy. "Ensure this value has at most 5 characters (it has 6)." But if you run the server in local, it works normally without errors.

I thought that postgresql connected to eb did not apply to migration, which led to an error i thought. However, after looking at the migration process through eb logs, we were able to confirm that it was applied normally without error.

What am I missing, what should I look at? Please give me a lot of advice.

+

There is one other change now. The same distribution was properly applied at the service server. No errors are generated. However, the development server generates an error even though it is the same distribution. Should we check the connection between aws eb and rds? What should I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. The server specified by config.yml in .elasticbeanstalk was a service server. In short, my distribution was applied to the actual service server, not to the development server, and the development server was not deployed, so errors continued. It is my mistake to enter the wrong folder. I thank many people who read the questions.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two options:

1. Your database is not up to date. Connect directly to the database and check `django_migrations`;
2. Your code is not being updated. Connect through ssh and check if the code deployed is what you expect.

Comment: There is one other change now. The same distribution was properly applied at the service server. No errors are generated. However, the development server generates an error even though it is the same distribution. Should we check the connection between aws eb and rds? What should I check?